# How to reference an element in an array to multiple other values?

Tags: c#

I would like to make a program that reads a text file (of book titles) and correspond each book title to a user rating. How would I go about assigning multiple ratings to a book title in the array?

So far I have,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("books.txt");

    }
```

The user ratings are in a separate text file in this form:

```
User:a
2 
5 
4 
1
1
User:b
5
5
0
1
2
```

If there are 5 books and two users, how can I relate the score of 2 and 5 to a book called "The Hunger Gamer"?

Comment: you want to do it in memory or in database?

Comment: I'msorry, I 'm really new to prgramming
What's the difference?

Comment: that doesn't answers my question. do you want to store these values in some database, or just in the program without involving any database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here. Like this

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> bookMapping = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
bookMapping.Add("youruserkey", new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
```

PS: Do read the link in detail of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have 3 pieces of data here: Book, User and Rating.  You could create structures for each of these and fill them with appropriate data, then you can do all sorts of interesting things with them.

Here's an example:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}

public class User
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}

public class Rating
{
    public int UserID;
    public int BookID;
    public int Value;
}
```

Starting at the basic level you could load a list of those items into arrays:

```
Book[] books = new Book[] 
    { 
        new Book { ID = 1, Name = "A B C" },
        new Book { ID = 2, Name = "Word Two" },
        new Book { ID = 3, Name = "Third Book" },
        new Book { ID = 4, Name = "And Another" },
        new Book { ID = 5, Name = "The Last Word" }
    };

User[] users = new User[] 
    { 
        new User { ID = 1, Name = "A" },
        new User { ID = 2, Name = "B" },
    };

Rating[] ratings = new Rating[] 
    {
        new Rating { UserID = 1, BookID = 1, Value = 2 },
        new Rating { UserID = 1, BookID = 2, Value = 5 },
        new Rating { UserID = 1, BookID = 3, Value = 4 },
        new Rating { UserID = 1, BookID = 4, Value = 1 },
        //new Rating { UserID = 1, BookID = 5, Value = 1 },
        new Rating { UserID = 2, BookID = 1, Value = 5 },
        new Rating { UserID = 2, BookID = 2, Value = 5 },
        new Rating { UserID = 2, BookID = 3, Value = 0 },
        new Rating { UserID = 2, BookID = 4, Value = 1 },
        //new Rating { UserID = 2, BookID = 5, Value = 2 },
    };
```

Now for some fun...

A list of average ratings for all of the books in your collection (including the ones that have no rating, the ones I commented out in the `ratings` initialiser):

```
var bookRatings = 
// start with books
    from bk in books
// get all the ratings related to each book...
    join r in ratings on bk.ID equals r.BookID into _ratings
// put a default value (null, no value) when no ratings were found
    from r in _ratings.DefaultIfEmpty()
// now group the ratings by book
    group (r == null ? null : (int?)r.Value) by bk into grp
// and now do some calculations:
    select new 
        {
            grp.Key.ID,
            grp.Key.Name,
            Rating = grp.Average(),
            NumRatings = grp.Count(v => v != null)
        };

// Now display it:
foreach (var result in bookRatings)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1,-15}\t{2}\t{3}", result.ID, result.Name, result.Rating, result.NumRatings);
```

Here's the output:

```
1   A B C           3.5 2
2   Word Two        5   2
3   Third Book      2   2
4   And Another     1   2
5   The Last Word       0
```

---

I've used [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx), [arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453.aspx), [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) and some fairly interesting [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) forms up there, but it's all good stuff to learn.  Click the links and do some reading until you understand most of what is happening above.

Incidentally, the above is pretty much exactly what I'd do if I was storing the data in a database - same structure overall, and almost the same code too.  [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) takes away a lot of the pain of implementation when you do transition.